# backup list of installed packages

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, backup, dpkg

I want to reinstall my linux system (specifically linux mint). I have kept important data elsewhere, so I can safely remove everything.

However, I want to do the following:

1. save the list of packages I have installed so far
2. after reinstall take the backup list and use it to install packages

Are there tools that can assist in doing this. I know I can use `dpkg -l` to get list but perhaps I only want the leafs - packages that no other depend on.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with using `dpkg --get-selections` is that it does not preserve some package states such as "automatically installed". To preserve all data, you can use the aptitude front-end to backup and restore the package list:

```
aptitude search -F '%100p' '~i!~M' > package_list #backup

xargs aptitude --schedule-only install < package_list
aptitude install #restore
```

Answer (score 4):

You can save you current list with

```
dpkg --get-selections > sel.list
```

and copy this file in safe place to be able copy it on a new machine. (and also you should backup your settings from /etc/ dir if you did some changes there)

To restore it with you should run:

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < sel.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -u dselect-upgrade
```

Comment: Is there a `dpkg` command that will list all modified configuration-files?

Comment: @Nils check this http://serverfault.com/questions/90400/how-to-check-for-modified-config-files-on-a-debian-system