# How to create an installable liveCD backup of my system (keep all installed packages but not home directories)

Tags: backup, livecd

What tool should be used to do this? I have taken a look a remastersys but the image it generated wasn't installable. (I could just boot it, and login, although all my packages were installed). If anyone knows a way of getting this image installable please tell me. I also looked at live build which seemed to allow you to customize a liveCD, but not clone an installation. Can anyone reccomend tools to use or guide me through steps to take?

Comment: possible duplicate of [backup list of installed packages](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67404/backup-list-of-installed-packages)